# changing windows c drive to create more partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

hi actually my problem is very specific.
i have four primary partitions

1. system 100mb - system which create while installing win 7
2. windows c drive -820 gb where my windows 7 is installed
3. ubuntu - 90 gb where ubuntu 13.10 is installed
4. swap partition - for ubuntu

all above are primary

i want to make one more partition in windows but this current situation doesn't allow me to do it.

i do not want to delete any OS.

please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply delete your swap partition.From that unallocated space create a new extended partition.There you will be able to create logical partitions(ext4,ntfs,etc).

Boot Ubuntu live disk or Gparted live disk to do the above operations.

Comment: wont it affect my ubuntu installation??

Comment: it won't, make sure all the partitions are unmounted and your swap partition is in `swap off` state.